# i have a matrix of 18*9, I want to calculate the mean values of 6 rows each and get a resultant matrix of 3*9

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to calculate the mean value of 6 rows each of a matrix 600*9 dimension. The new matrix should be of size 100*9. Can someone help me ?

I saw this code for calculating mean of 2 rows each and it is working fine foe 2 rows :-

```
x = rand(1028, 18);

result1 = zeros(1028/2, 18); 
for ii = 1:1028/2;
    result1(ii,:) = mean(x((2*ii-1):(2*ii),:)); 
end;
```

The output  matrix will have the mean of first 6 rows ( of the input matrix)  as the first row and next 6 rows as the 2nd row and so on

Comment: In the title you say you have a 18-by-9 matrix, in the text 600-by-9, and in the code 1028-by-18. Which is it? Or shall we just say: 6 equal sizes groups along the first dimension?

Answer (score 2):

Let the data be defined as

```
x = rand(600, 9); % example data
N = 6; % group size
```

The desired result can be obtained very easily without loops:

1. Reshape the data matrix as a 3-D array, where the size along the first dimension is the desired group size;
2. Compute the mean along the first dimension;
3. Remove the first dimension, which is now a singleton.

```
result = reshape(mean(reshape(x, N, [], size(x,2)), 1), [], size(x,2));
```

Note how this single line contains the three steps described above:

```
                      reshape(x, N, [], size(x,2))                       % step 1
                 mean(                            , 1)                   % step 2
result = reshape(                                     , [], size(x,2));  % step 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mean` and a `for` loop:

```
data = rand(600,9);
num_groups = 6;
group_size = size(data,1)/num_groups;

mean_by_group = NaN(num_groups, size(data,2));

for k = 1:num_groups
    mean_by_group(k,:) = mean(data((k-1)*group_size+(1:group_size),:),1)
end
```

Comment: @LuisMendo ah indeed, fixed.